# Error: An unexpected error has occurred. Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have updated firebase-functions to version 1.0.2, firebase-tools to 3.18.4, firebase-admin to 5.12.0

I am uploading a function that generate thumbnails taken from https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/thumbnails

```
[debug] [2018-04-26T09:00:12.812Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 400

[debug] [2018-04-26T09:00:12.812Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid argument.</Message></Error>

[debug] [2018-04-26T09:00:12.813Z] TypeError: Cannot create property 'error' on string '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid argument.</Message></Error>'
at module.exports (C:\Users\NASA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\responseToError.js:11:16)
at Request._callback

(C:\Users\NASA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\api.js:47:25)
at Request.self.callback

(C:\Users\NASA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
at Request.emit (domain.js:421:20)
at Request.<anonymous> 

(C:\Users\NASA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
at Request.emit (domain.js:421:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> 

(C:\Users\NASA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:1085:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)


[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Comment: Can you share the code of you Cloud Function?

Comment: Did you make the nessecary changes when updating firebase-functions? Check out [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)

Comment: The code is cloned from  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/thumbnails and no single line is added i am using "firebase deploy" to deploy

Answer (score 1):

You said that:

1. You have updated firebase-functions to version 1.0.2
2. The code is cloned from the Cloud Function sample without any change

So most probably your problem comes form the fact that Cloud Functions V1.0.0 and above have changed, see the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#storage

You should change from

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
```

to

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object, context) => {
```

and adapt accordingly the lines based on object, following the doc.